# hierarchical bootstrapping and calculation of variance (in a Random-Effects ROC Analysis) in R

Tags: r, roc, auc, clustered-standard-errors

I would like to calculate the variance of the AUC of `readers` (for each reader and averaged results) giving a `score`(1-5)  to specific `areas` (1-5) of `cases` using two different `modalities`.

**Test data:**

```
df <-data.frame(
              modality=rep(c("A","B"),each=25,2),
              reader=rep(c("reader1","reader2"),each=50),
              case= rep(c("1","2","3","4","5"),each=5,2),
              area=rep(c("a1","a2","a3","a4","a5"),20),
              score=sample(1:5,100, replace=TRUE),
              disease=rep(sample(0:1,25, replace=TRUE),4),
              stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

> df
    modality  reader case  area score disease
1          A reader1    1   a1     5       0
2          A reader1    1   a2     3       0
3          A reader1    1   a3     4       1
4          A reader1    1   a4     2       0
5          A reader1    1   a5     5       1
6          A reader1    2   a1     1       1
7          A reader1    2   a2     3       1
```

**Suggested Method (from 1):**

DBM refers to (2)

Davison and Hinkley refers to (3)

BWC refers to (4)

[image: Manual from [1]]

**What I know**

I found a solution how to do the first step (two-way bootstrap):
[Bootstrapping hierarchical/multilevel data (resampling clusters)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46821/bootstrapping-hierarchical-multilevel-data-resampling-clusters)

```
# dplyr
library(dplyr)

replicate(100, {
  cluster_sample <- data.frame(case= sample(df$case, replace = TRUE))
  dat_sample <- df %>% inner_join(cluster_sample, by = "case")
  dat_sample
})
```

I know how to calculate the AUC for reader 1 and 2 and the average AUC

```
library(pROC)
roc1 <- roc(df[which(df$reader=="reader1"&df$modality=="A"),]$disease, df[which(df$reader=="reader1"&df$modality=="A"),]$score)
roc1 <- roc(df[which(df$reader=="reader2"&df$modality=="A"),]$disease, df[which(df$reader=="reader2"&df$modality=="A"),]$score)
rocm <- multiclass.roc(df[which(df$modality=="A"),]$disease, df[which(df$modality=="A"),]$score)
```

**What I cannot replicate**

I do not know how to apply the second part of the method stated above to get the correct variances (yellow marked part)

**Reference**

1. Gallas BD, Bandos A, Samuelson FW, Wagner RF. A Framework for Random-Effects ROC Analysis: Biases with the Bootstrap and Other Variance Estimators. Communications in Statistics - Theory and Methods. 2009 Jul 23;38(15):2586–603. 
   https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610920802610084
2. Dorfman DD, Berbaum KS, Metz CE. Receiver operating characteristic rating analysis. Generalization to the population of readers and patients with the jackknife method. Invest Radiol. 1992 Sep;27(9):723–31.
3. Davidson, A. C., Hinkley, D. V. (1997). Bootstrap methods and their applications. Cambridge University press.
4. Beiden SV, Wagner RF, Campbell G. Components-of-variance models and multiple-bootstrap experiments: An alternative method for random-effects, receiver operating characteristic analysis. Academic Radiology. 2000 May;7(5):341–9. 
   https://www.academicradiology.org/article/S1076-6332(00)80008-2/pdf

Comment: This problem is being solved with the help of Brandon D. Gallas and his R-package iMRMC, the implementation is discussed at https://github.com/DIDSR/iMRMC/issues/147